# ReactCSSTransitionGroup doesn't add classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add animation to each list item of a list of articles i'm loading with an ajax request.
This is my component for the list of articles, but the ReactCSSTransitionGroup element has no effect on the items it's applied to: it doesn't add classes.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem, ListGroupItemHeading, ListGroupItemText } from 'reactstrap';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

export default ({
  articles
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="col-md-8 col-10 mx-auto">
      <ListGroup className="results">
        {articles.map((article, idx) => {
          return (
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
              transitionName="article"
              transitionEnterTimeout={500}
              transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
              <ListGroupItem key={idx}>
                <ListGroupItemHeading>
                  <a target="_blank" href={`https://wikipedia.org/wiki/${article.title}`}>
                    {article.title}
                  </a>
                </ListGroupItemHeading>
                <ListGroupItemText dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: article.snippet}}>
                </ListGroupItemText>
              </ListGroupItem>
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
          );
        })}
      </ListGroup>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is driving me nuts, I did everything right and it just won't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

There is a working example [here](https://codepen.io/agrewell/pen/ZYdGOJ).

If you want to animate on initial mounting you will need [transitionAppear](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html#animate-initial-mounting).

In your code each item a transitiongroup, the example has the list as one group so maybe this works:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem, ListGroupItemHeading, ListGroupItemText } from 'reactstrap';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

export default ({
  articles
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="col-md-8 col-10 mx-auto">
      <ListGroup className="results">
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                transitionName="article"
                transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
          {articles.map((article, idx) => {
            return (
                <ListGroupItem key={idx}>
                  <ListGroupItemHeading>
                    <a target="_blank" href={`https://wikipedia.org/wiki/${article.title}`}>
                      {article.title}
                    </a>
                  </ListGroupItemHeading>
                  <ListGroupItemText dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: article.snippet}}>
                  </ListGroupItemText>
                </ListGroupItem>
            );
          })}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      </ListGroup>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If it doesn't maybe you could provide a codepen example.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem, all I had to do is use CSSTransitionGroup from react-transition-group. I don't know why but it's working perfectly now.